# How to ensure that apache-ant apply-tasks finish before further execution

Tags: apache, ant

I use the following code to resolve all PHP includes and create a static html file. When this is done, I want to delete the source php file:

```
<apply executable="php" parallel="false" dir="${prod.dir}" output="${prod.dir}/index.html">
  <fileset dir="${prod.dir}" includes="index.php"/>
</apply>
<delete file="${prod.dir}/index.php"/>
```

Apparently, index.php gets deleted while php is running. How can I make sure the delete task is executed only after php is completed?

I know I could wait for a second or so, but would rather not want to rely on this.

Thanks
Stefan

Comment: does  php run in background or foreground?

Comment: I run the build.xml file just by calling ant in the terminal or by executing a shell script which in turn just calls ant. In about 5% of the cases, only the first part of the source php file gets processed, which makes me think that it is deleted while it is being processed. As you said, spawn is false by default. I tested with setting it explicitly, but cannot proof so far that this would solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the property `spawn` is set to `false` ( default is `false`), then ant should wait till it is complete. The `delete` will be called only after php is complete.

[Apply task manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html)

Comment: Thanks yan. The problem has never occurred again. I suppose something else was going on, but didn't spend more time on it. You answer matches the docs.